# Orbeon dropdown values on reload in firefox not visible

Tags: firefox, caching, autocomplete, orbeon

I have created a form which has several dropdown fields in it.
In my specific case, the same form can be opened in two browsers.
If I edit the form in e.g. Chrome, and reload it in Firefox, all of the values are visible except for the ones which were set for dropdowns.

I've read that the autocomplete="off" attribute should be set to disable caching in Firefox, but unfortunately, that hasn't worked in my case. I've also tried adding the xxf:autocomplete="off" in the form definition, but without any luck.

Is there a known bug for this issue or maybe a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is what *should* happen in Firefox for text fields: when you reload the form (e.g. ctrl-r), if the user hasn't changed the value after the initial load, the browser will show the value coming from the server, otherwise it will keep the value the user had entered. Is this inline with what you're seeing? Are you saying that you'd like Firefox to always display the value coming from the server, even if the user had changed the value (as on Chrome)?

Comment: Masha, also see [request for enhancement 3542](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3542), and you'll let me know if this sounds like what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes, so, in my case, the form is saved with some values (done in Chrome)
When I refresh the page with the form in Firefox, the values are missing and I can't submit the form (even though there are no error messages, since the form, essentially is filled out).
The behaviour I'd like is the one describe in the request for enhancement (for all browsers)

Comment: Got it, and I also think that what you're suggesting would make sense. I've been experimenting to see if adding a `autocomplete="off"` on the `<form>` might solve this, but it is a non-starter (see my comment on [#3542](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3542)). So we'll need to do more investigation on this one. In the meantime, would asking Firefox users to do a `ctrl-F5` or `ctrl-shift-r` be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
For now, since this is a technical issue, and I think it will be alright to ask the customer to do so (for now).
Is this an issue caused by Orbeon or Firefox? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: It's an intended behavior in Firefox, and they had this for as long as I remember. For instance, take a plain form like the [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search), enter values in a few fields, and hit reload. On Chrome the fields are empty after the reload (they show whatever was sent by the browser), but Firefox will repopulate them with the values you had entered. Chrome also does the repopulation if you navigate away from the form and come back (and so does Firefox), but not if you reload the form.